# How to hide h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: html, css, jsf

I am using custom check box idea

[Ryan Fait's Idea](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Where you can use custom images in order to create custom check boxes. But I am unable to make the check box disappear, and just have the regular box. Example image here 
 [image: Notice that the checkboxes are still there...]

Here is my code..

```
  <div id="scheduleContainer">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <!--table header-->
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>                                            
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{schedules[scheduleName][0]}" /><label> 12:00AM</label>
</td>

    </div>
```

inside the css

```
#scheduleContainer .checkbox {
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(../img/schedule-check.gif) no-repeat;
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Also given was the js file. Am i using this correctly?

```
/*
CUSTOM CHECK BOXES - Derived from script by Ryan Fait at
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ 
*/

var checkboxHeight = "20";

/* No need to change anything after this */


document.write('<style type="text/css">.styledGroup input { display: none; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
    init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

                if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                    position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                }
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                    span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
                } else {
                    span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
        document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
    },
    pushed: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
        } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
        }
    },
    check: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            element.checked = false;
        } else {
            if(element.type == "checkbox") {
                this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } 
            element.checked = true;
        }
    },
    clear: function() {
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
            if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply CSS `display: none;` on the HTML generated by `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

E.g.

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox style="display: none;" />
```

or

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="hide" />
```

with

```css
.hide { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Yes that definitely works, but that's exactly what I did in the CSS, why didn't that work?

Comment: You're talking about the `.styledGroup input` class? Well, perhaps because those checkboxes are not inside some element with `class="styledGroup"`?